# Calculate Time interval with two dates in excel

Tags: excel, date, time, intervals

Currently creating a file that calculates number of heads that renders Overtime per interval. My problem is when the end time falls on the next day

Comment: Please give a good explanation to your question(along with examples if possible).

Comment: Hi Guys, apologies , I dont know how to set it up here, so I just created a shared Gsheet -

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FjdKkVeIccxTx2jkZRQR-i5SXD60dhIYEuFVAwUGY-s/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about your Problem ?

Answer (score 0):

If `A1` is a datetime and `B1` is another datetime, then you should be able to do this in `C1`: `=B1-A1`

Comment: Hi Guys, apologies , I dont know how to set it up here, so I just created a shared Gsheet -

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FjdKkVeIccxTx2jkZRQR-i5SXD60dhIYEuFVAwUGY-s/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I only have the date of the start time and the end time falls on the next day